# How does let binding work

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, let

I'm new to Haskell and I'm having troubles understanding how the let binding works in the following example:

```
prefixes :: [a] -> [[a]] 

prefixes xs =
    let prefix n = take n xs
    in map prefix (range (length xs))
```

'take' function returns a list, so how does this get bind to 2 variables (prefix n)? Or am I totally missing the point here...

Comment: `prefix n` is a function taking `n` as argument and returning the list.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but the `let` creates a local function called `prefix`, then it's used to map over the `range`. You can tell `prefix` is a function because it says that it takes a parameter `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `let` as syntactic sugar for using an anonymous function.

`let name = value in stuff` is equivalent to `(\name -> stuff) value`. An anonymous function whose body is the expression in the `in` clause is applied to the expression bound to a name in the `let` clause.